# ArcGIS Collector using WFS as source layer?

Tags: arcgis-collector, arcgis-portal

We have situation with external company layer service that is included in Web Portal map. 
This layer service provide some environment data that changes frequently (e.g. 5 per day). 
We want to have the data included in ArcGIS Collector offline mode - as a read-only, supporting layer.

But we do NOT want to copy & synch. data from external service to our own ArcGIS database several times a day, add GlobalID&Archiving (by following SDI principles we try to use referencing instead of unnecessary copying). Of course, we cannot change the external service layer (to add GlobalID etc)

Is there no way to get such layers on Collector ?

Comment: You mention WFS in your question title but not in your question body or tags.  How is it involved?

Comment: Sorry - "external company layer service" is a WFS service

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with requested details such as this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layer would need to have sync enabled if it is a feature service to be taken offline. If it was a tiled service it would have to support export tiles. Without either of those configurations the data cannot be taken offline.

Comment: Yes, I read about that - this GlobalID/sync requirement is obvious  in the cases we collect/update objects in the field. I hope there is a way to include read-only vector data from other sources than ArcGIS Database (WFS, native SQL Server tables with geography e.g. Query Layers etc.)